# Flutter cannot use URL variable inside Image.network widget

Tags: flutter

Im trying to get url from cloud firebase and then use it in Image.network but it doesn't work..
When i hardcode the url inside Image.network it works.. the variable did get the url as the data.

I get an error from image.dart - ImageStreamListener throw error.

this is my code:

---

```
class _MemoryCardState extends State<MemoryCard> {
  Map<String, dynamic> photos = {};

  Future getPhoto() async {
    photos.clear();
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('photos');
    await db.doc(widget.id).get().then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      photos = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Card(
          semanticContainer: true,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          elevation: 10,
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: deviceWidth * 0.8,
            height: deviceWidth * 0.35,
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Memory()));
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder(
                      future: getPhoto(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        String url = photos['url'].toString();
                        return Hero(
                            tag: 'image',
                            child: Image.network(
                              url,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              width: deviceWidth * 0.8,
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
                            ));
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.2),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Can you print the url and add to description?

Comment: I/flutter (19192): null
I/flutter (19192): https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1N4HR0wK0jQpEpXSmjuaQwNjpT1eHxMfz

 this comes out
it prints null but then when it got the data from db it prints out the url

Answer (score 0):

give the url which you found from firebase.
If you used URI as DataType in firebase then it is the problem.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1N4HR0wK0jQpEpXSmjuaQwNjpT1eHxMfz

this is the url in the database .. the image appears in my app if i hardcode the url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).